# AppleScript keystrokes

Tags: applescript, keystroke

I have a problem with the keystrokes when I use the system events in applescript application. Indeed, when I run the applescript program with keystrokes in system events, the message: "The name of the program is not allowed to send key entries" error 1002 appears. I have already authorized the AppleScript program in the security and privacy and privacy section but despite everything, the message appears. Note that this AppleScript program works well in the AppleScript format before becoming a program. I can't fix this problem.

Comment: Also check the Automation list to see if everything is still enabled for the app.

Comment: red_menace. I checked the Automation list as you said and it has been done. I mean my application script was checked "√ " for the system events associated with the name of my applescript. And for sure, I tried to run it and the same message error appeared. I began to get fed up with this